# Creating a database from a .csv file

Tags: python, csv

I need to take a .csv file, open the file, read the file, then create a database, which is a dictionary whose keys are years and values are a list with a tuple in it, like so:

```
db = {2002:[('Andrew', 5, 63, 75000)], etc…}
```

The categories that I need are 'Name', Category, deaths, DamageMillions

This is a snap of the data that I am working with:

[image]

How would I do this?

Edit: I know how to open and read the file, I just don't know how to create the database.

Comment: The spreadsheet *is* a database!  What more do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *untested* but should give you a good idea where to start:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

db = defaultdict(list)
with open('csvfile.csv') as f:
     csvreader = csv.reader(f)
     for row in csvreader:
         db[row[0]].append((row[1], row[4], row[5], row[6]))

return db
```

More info on [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

Use the csv module in conjunction with DictReader.
You'll get a list of dictionaries to iterate over, which you'll have to transform to get your desired year indices.

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html